# R: when both events (columns) are true, refer to one of them to decide the value

Tags: r, xts

I want to manipulate two columns in R, so that when both events are true, refer to one of the columns to decide the value. For example:

```
a<- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
b<- c(0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0)
```

when a and b are both true, at a[9] and a[10], refer to b to decide the value of another column c in the following lines. Then, if b is FALSE at some line, (here is line 17) check again if both a and b are true. So, the desired output is like this:

```
c<- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0)
data <- cbind(a,b,c)
data
      a b c
 [1,] 0 0 0
 [2,] 0 1 0
 [3,] 0 1 0
 [4,] 0 0 0
 [5,] 0 0 0
 [6,] 1 0 0
 [7,] 1 0 0
 [8,] 1 0 0
 [9,] 1 1 1
[10,] 1 1 1
[11,] 0 1 1
[12,] 0 1 1
[13,] 0 1 1
[14,] 0 1 1
[15,] 0 1 1
[16,] 0 1 1
[17,] 0 0 0
[18,] 0 0 0
```

As the data comes in many lines, I would prefer the use vectorized method like ifelse() to handle this.

Many thanks to all the people who can help me with this.

Comment: why is c[11] is 1 while c[2] is 0? yet in both cases a is 0 and b is1??

Comment: So, I should make it clear that when both events (here a and b) are true, refer to b to decide the value of c. The first line when both a and b are true is line 9, after-wards b is true until line 16, so c is true from line 9 to line 16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the issue but here is a tidyverse solution that reproduces the output:

```
a<- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
b<- c(0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0)
df <- data.frame(a,b)

library(tidyverse)
df %>% mutate(c=case_when(
  a == 1 & b == 1 ~ 1,
  a == 0 & b == 0 ~ 0,
  TRUE ~ NA_real_
)) %>% fill(c)

#    a b c
# 1  0 0 0
# 2  0 1 0
# 3  0 1 0
# 4  0 0 0
# 5  0 0 0
# 6  1 0 0
# 7  1 0 0
# 8  1 0 0
# 9  1 1 1
# 10 1 1 1
# 11 0 1 1
# 12 0 1 1
# 13 0 1 1
# 14 0 1 1
# 15 0 1 1
# 16 0 1 1
# 17 0 0 0
# 18 0 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much Moody, This is exactly what I want. I will get to learn the tideyverse function right now.